# How to highlight/pullout the difference between two cells

Tags: excel, vba

I need to compare two values and highlight the difference if any.

The below snippet is saying equal or not but along with that I need to highlight the values.

Cells contains a list of string values.

```
Public Sub Overview_LRF()

    If (Range("L2").Value = Range("L5").Value) Then

        Gazellevalidation2.OverviewProjects.Value = "Equals"

    Else
        Gazellevalidation2.OverviewProjects.Value = "Not Equals"

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try conditional formatting?

Answer (score 3):

```
Sub HighlightDuplicateValues()

    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim myCell As Range

    Set myRange = Selection

    For Each myCell In myRange
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(myRange, myCell.Value) > 1 Then
            myCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 36
        End If
    Next myCell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

On the same lines, made a macro to find difference in two cells by checking character by character. Some times this kind of situations do occur, where we need to find out the difference by character.

- Paste data in adjacent columns, like col A, Col B
- Data in Col A and B will be same like A1="David",B1="Davi1d", with a difference.
- Select first column and run the macro
- Macro will check thecell and the adjacent cell and highlight the    difference.

---

```
Sub ChkDiff()
    i = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, ActiveCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
    Set myRange = Selection
    For Each Cell In myRange
        L1 = Len(Cell.Value)
        L2 = Len(Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value)
        If L1 > L2 Then
            LENT = L1
        Else
            LENT = L2
        End If
        'Cells(j, ActiveCell.Column).Select
        For x = 1 To LENT
            v1 = Cell.Characters(1, x).Text
            v2 = Cell.Offset(0, 1).Characters(1, x).Text
            If v1 <> v2 Then
                Cell.Characters(x, 1).Font.Color = VBA.RGB(255, 0, 0)
            End If
        Next x
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

See this example below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()

    Dim in1 As Range
    Dim in2 As Range
    Dim out As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim iLen As Long

    Set in1 = Cells(1, 1)
    Set in2 = Cells(1, 2)
    Set out = Cells(1, 3)

    If in1.Value2 = in2.Value2 Then
        out = "<identical>"
    Else
        out.Value2 = vbNullString
        iLen = Len(in1.Value2)
        For i = 1 To iLen        ' find the 1st mismatch
            If in1.Characters(i, 1).Text <> in2.Characters(i, 1).Text Then Exit For
        Next i
        If i <= iLen Then
            out.Value2 = in1.Value2
        Else
            out.Value2 = in2.Value2
            iLen = Len(in2.Value2)
        End If
        out.Characters(i, iLen - i + 1).Font.Color = vbRed
            ' you can make it more robust here
            ' handling nullstring output or space char
    End If

End Sub
```

If you need more sophisticated comparison, you might consider Fuzzy Lookup Add-In for Excel.